# Using a for loop to push items onto a Map in JavaScript reverses the order of the array

Tags: javascript

Why is the order in the below code reversed in the array that is created?

```js
let conns =  [
    {"jobId":"BPOM","id":{"makeupUID":"4"}},
    {"jobId":"BPOM","id":{"makeupUID":"3"}},
    {"jobId":"BPOM","id":{"makeupUID":"2"}},
    {"jobId":"BPOM","id":{"makeupUID":"1"}}];


console.log(`Before: ${JSON.stringify(conns)}`)
    let unique = new Map();
    for (let item of conns) {
      unique[item.id.makeupUID] = item;
    }
    
    this._allConnections = Object.values(unique);
    console.log(`After: ${JSON.stringify(this._allConnections)}`)
```

The order of the array is reversed in the forloop.  Is it because the key is a string?
I have done fiddles on this and I don't get consistant results.

For the below fiddle, the result array is just the element with id of 3.  Here is the screen shot to show the fiddle.
What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: You are using `of` in your first sample and `in` in your second. They have different functionality.

Comment: 1. You are not using the map correctly. You should be adding values using [.set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set). You're currently just adding plain object properties. 2. Since you're adding plain object properties, the default ordering of integer keys is in ascending order.

Comment: @ToddSkelton Your so right.  Silly Mistake.  Thank you

Comment: Ok, I was using map incorrectly.  Thank you @VLAZ

Comment: @VLAD The makeupUID in the 1st example was a string.  So did you mean that the default ordering of the string keys is also in ascending order?

Comment: No - *all* keys on an object are represented as either the string type or symbol type. There technically aren't any numeric keys - numbers are just converted to strings. However, integer keys (more specifically, positive ones - anything that is a valid index in an array) are treated differently and (mostly) sorted *before* any other keys and in ascending order. Then come string keys (which includes negative integers and any other number) in insertion order, finally symbol keys in insertion order (they are sorted last).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people by now pointed out in the comments, you need to use `.set()` to insert elements into the map, and `.values` to get them out again. Otherwise you are actually butchering your Map object with additional fields that don't belong there, but certainly don't do want you want, namely use the properties of Map.

```js
let conns =  [
  {"jobId":"BPOM","id":{"makeupUID":"4"}},
  {"jobId":"BPOM","id":{"makeupUID":"3"}},
  {"jobId":"BPOM","id":{"makeupUID":"2"}},
  {"jobId":"BPOM","id":{"makeupUID":"1"}}];
  
  
console.log(`Before: ${JSON.stringify(conns)}`)
let unique = new Map();
for (let item of conns) {
  unique.set(item.id.makeupUID, item);
}

this._allConnections = Array.from(unique.values());
console.log(`After: ${JSON.stringify(this._allConnections)}`)
```

Comment: Christian, this is what I have done but when debugging, I get an empty array.  Here is my new code.    ```console.log(`Before: ${JSON.stringify(conns)}`)
    let unique = new Map();
    for (let item of conns) {
      unique.set(item.id.makeupUID, item);
    }

    this._allConnections = Object.values(unique);
    console.log(`After: ${JSON.stringify(this._allConnections)}`) ```

Comment: Please re-read my code. You can't use `Object.values(unique);` as I said. You need to use `unique.values()`.

Comment: Thank you @Christian, I realized that before I saw your last note.